# Sharepoint 2013 always asking for credentials vs Virus Warning when clicking a file

Tags: internet-explorer, credentials

If I've added my SharePoint site to the 'Local Intranet' zone I get the 'Some files contain viruses that can be harmful...' warning every time I click on a file.

If I've added my SharePoint site as a 'Trusted Site' I am asked for my credentials every time I go to the site even if I have the box checked to save my credentials.

Is there not something that can be done to prevent both of these scenarios at the same time?

Comment: are you clikcing on Hyper link and those are Office file?

Comment: Yes i'm clicking on a hyperlink to an Office File

Answer (score 1):

So this is not the SharePoint problem rather a built-in security feature.

Please read these article to understand it.

[Virus warning appears when you click hyperlink to program](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183923)

This will help you fix the virus error.

[How to enable or disable hyperlink warning messages in 2007 Office programs and in Office 2010 programs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925757)